# Cannot fetch array values from API

Tags: java, android

I'm new to API data fetching and I have used this [ThingSpeak API library for Android.](https://github.com/MacroYau/ThingSpeakAndroid.git) to get JSON data from a Thingspeak URL to my Java Android application.

The JSON data looks like this

```
{"channel":

        {"id":1382053,"name":"WeightScale","latitude":"0.0","longitude":"0.0","field1":"weight",
        "created_at":"2021-05-06T05:18:16Z","updated_at":"2021-05-06T05:18:16Z","last_entry_id":207},
        
    "feeds":
        [
            {"created_at":"2021-05-07T16:26:06Z","entry_id":206,"field1":"0.00000"},
            {"created_at":"2021-05-07T16:26:22Z","entry_id":207,"field1":"2.00000"}
        ]
}
```

and my MainActivity contains

```
package com.dommy.qrcodelib;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.ThingSpeakChannel;
import com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.ChannelFeed;

import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ThingSpeakChannel tsChannel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        fetchData();
    }

    public void fetchData() {
        tsChannel = new ThingSpeakChannel(1382053,"[MyAPIKey]");
        // Set listener for Channel feed update events
        tsChannel.setChannelFeedUpdateListener(new ThingSpeakChannel.ChannelFeedUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChannelFeedUpdated(long channelId, String channelName, ChannelFeed channelFeed) {
               
                long entry = channelFeed.getChannel().getLastEntryId();
                Log.e(null,""+ entry); 
                Date lastUpdate = channelFeed.getChannel().getUpdatedAt();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lastUpdate.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
                //unable to get last data value from here onwards (instead prints lots of entries) 
                
                 String d = channelFeed.getFeeds().toString();
                 Log.e(null,""+ d); 
            }
        });
        
        tsChannel.loadChannelFeed();

    }
}
```

**I need to print a log with the last field1 value that was received. (eg: 2.00000 needs to be printed)**

The current code only prints an output similar to:

```
E/dommy.qrcodeli: [com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@90c638d, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@ca98942, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@70dbd53, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@1bb1690, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@e8ab89, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@c4af78e, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@92cdbaf, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@b630bbc, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@6277745, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@982fe9a, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@b7583cb, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@93327a8, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@4cd42c1, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@8026a66, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@65691a7, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@1671654, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@aaa49fd, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@3bac6f2, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@50a143, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@4943c0, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@85688f9, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@42a603e, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@d520e9f, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@a5edbec, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@5edbbb5, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@868424a, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@7d2f5bb, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@553cad8, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@78b5e31, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@7f03916, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@fb13297, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@3a6bc84, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@d86ac6d, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@42ed0a2, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@acc6133, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@f151cf0, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@c6ea269, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@6cd54ee, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@361dd8f, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@dc7181c, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@8c5fc25, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@8bdd1fa, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@28c3ab, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@e3b9a08, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@27f35a1, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@e0713c6, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@22def87, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@5f44eb4, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@c388add, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@250a652, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@46ffd23, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@ee1a220, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@a37f7d9, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@22ed59e, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@93b487f, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@f8ec04c, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@5273895, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@d2eadaa, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@145ed9b, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@a0d9538, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@c8fc911, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@ca1fa76, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@88bc877, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@da2cce4, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@516e54d, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@b2b4802, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@4ea7513, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@731d350, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@e798949, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@909e24e, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@27d4f6f, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@c68d47c, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@d487105, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@925d55a, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@9b9738b, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@dacbc68, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@4641881, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@2dbed26, com.macroyau.thingspeakandroid.model.Feed@b49bd67, com.macroyau.thingspeakan
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10000; state: DISABLED
E/dommy.qrcodeli: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code represents a JSON Array and not a JSON Object.

`getFeeds()` must return a list of `Feed` objects. Find the last `Feed` object based on the `lastEntryId` and which gives you a `feedObject`. Now you can print the `feedObject.field1` value.

This is a pseudo-code in Kotlin for help.

```
val feedList = channelFeed.getFeeds()
val feed = feedList.find { it.entryId == lastEntryId }
Log.d("TAG", "Value is " + feed.field1)
```

Comment: i tried passing data by adding 

 Object feed= channelFeed.getFeeds();
               String d = feed.toString();   

but it still gives the same output.

Comment: toString is not a good approach. Better use the actual fields to print the logs. `Feed` is an object class. If you print the toString of the object, you will just get the address. Either you modify the toString in the object to get the desired result or you use the actual property value which is a string. I suggest use the actual property value. Casting to the standard object class is not correct. You need to have a specific model with data types. Like Feed has 3 fields `createdAt`, `entryId` and `field1` of the types `String`, `Long` and `String` respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much! using the property values worked!

Comment: @DenverShenal Glad that I was able to help. I would appreciate it if you could upvote the answer and the comments if you found them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Here you are getting a string representation of your object means every class in java is a child of the Object class either directly or indirectly. Object class contains toString() method. We can use the toString() method to get a string representation of an object. Whenever we try to print the Object reference then internally toString() method is invoked.

**Solution:** In your Pojo or Model class you have to override the toString, hashCode and equals method to get the real value of your objects.

Example:-

```
    public class Person {
   private String name;
   private int age = 0;

   public Person(String name, int age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public int getAge() {
       return age;
   }

   public void setAge(int age) {
       this.age = age;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

       Person person = (Person) o;

       if (name != null ? !name.equals(person.name) : person.name != null) return false;
       if (age != 0 ? age != person.age : person.age != 0) return false;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
       result = 31 * result + age;
       return result;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Person{" +
               "name='" + name + '\'' +
               ", age='" + age + '\'' +
               '}';
   }
}
```

Comment: can you mark the answer correct please and also give it an upvote?..